# Display hierarchical structure and corresponding reference data

Tags: hierarchy, tree

Do any of you have any suggestion on how to design view for reference data and make it easy to navigate and understand. We are developing a web application and have this hierarchical setup:

- 1 corporation that can have X numbers of large teams below
- Each large team can have X number of small teams below
- A small team can belong to several larger teams (Z belongs to both A and B in the image below)
- Each level in this hierarchy can have X numbers of accounts and GUI-users

[image]

We need to have a view (or perhaps views) where it’s possible to find all entities and view a details “page” with more information for each entity.

It should be possible to

- query and find all larger and/or smaller teams
- find all accounts a specific team owns
- a user from a smaller team should be able to find all larger teams he belongs to
- Given an account, find the smaller team that owns it and what larger teams it belongs to

We are considering a combinations of list structures, where the first one more or less acts as a tree structure and displays the hierarchal team structure. 
[image]

When selecting a team all users below that team are displayed as well as the details for the specific team. If/when selecting a user the details to the right is replaced with the user details. For a team you can in the details view see all teams that it belongs to/are below. The downside with this solution is that a smaller team will be duplicated in the tree structure under all larger teams it belongs to.

Questions:

- Anyone that has tried a similar solution?
- Is it obvious that the users are only the ones that are on the specific node/entity you are viewing, so if you have selected Corporation you get only the users for that level, NOT all users (e.g all users below)?

  - Where/how should the accounts be displayed?

If anyone has a better solution I'm up for anything :)

Comment: did you go with this solution?

Comment: I suggest you combine the search fields into one. You can make it a bit smarter via control keywords, e.g., `user: superman` or `group:heroes`.

Answer (score 1):

Have worked on a few applications that rely on users navigating hierarchy structures like yours, and whilst the other solutions below are creative they just aren't natural for a user, and a treeview is generally always a best fit.

One additional option you have aside from treeview is that if you're able to group the teams (i.e. Large/Small) you can simply have a filter bar that has the options 'Select Large Team' & 'Select Small Team', the disadvantage here is that it just adds an extra step to the user getting the information they want to see.

I would personally go with the treeview structure, and implement breadcrumbs so users can easily switch to view their parent teams details as well. I would make the treeview more prominent as a navigation tool, along with a page title and breadcrumbs - you instantly give feedback to the user of what's controlling their view. Have attached a quick sketch of what this may look like (plus an additional way of displaying users, but don't know enough about your requirements to know if this helps or not) [image: treeview example]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have found your solution by now, but I'm wondering if a possiblity would be to put Big Teams in a dropdown filter list, and return Small Teams and their users when the user makes a selection. I think that would look cleaner. Something like:

[image]

The small team members could be co-mingled by default (because they all belong to the large team) and sorted alphabetically. The small team panel on the left could support child elements (Smaller team G under Small team A, etc.)

Interested to know what you landed on.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a combination of the [hierarchy](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/hierarchy) and [master-detail](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/master-details) patterns, expressed with Grid view or other suitable UI elements.